# Using pip and easy_install in virtualenv on Windows

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to install a few packages in a virtual environment using pip. I was getting the error:

```
Downloading/unpacking pymongo
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pymongo
No distributions at all found for pymongo
```

I found that some say a workaround is downgrading your pip. I downloaded and installed [pip 1.2.1](https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/1.2.1) Now I get the error:

```
(env1)PS C:\dev\virtualenvs> pip install bottle
Downloading/unpacking bottle
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement bottle
No distributions at all found for bottle
```

The log says:

```
urlopen error [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions>
```

How do I correctly use virtualenvs on windows?

EDIT: I am able to use pip when not in my virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the operating system should not matter. Also this should not be a question about `virtualenv` (as suggested in your title). `pip` just cannot access the remote end that it would like to access. Does it take some time for the error message to appear (is this a timeout issue)? If yes, then this is a networking issue, maybe triggered by a firewall. You should check this first.

Comment: I can use pip when I'm not in virtualenv. I should have mentioned that.